# windows automation with ruby win32ole - access an enum

Tags: ruby, win32ole

accessing methods and properties from ruby win32ole gem seems easy, but what do I do when I have to set an enum  more specifically, i am trying to set one of the values defined by [warningLevelOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.warningleveloption.aspx)   defined for [VCProjectEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.aspx)  but nothing seems to work.  none of the objects accessible via win32ole , will not recognize this enum,  and setting an integer value causes an exception in visual studio

how can I set this value ?